# How to write a setter for a mutableList?

Tags: kotlin

I was trying to do this, but it did not work

```
var stringList = mutableListOf<String>()
    set(value) {
        field = value
        validateData()
    }
```

somehow validateData() did not run

Comment: Please post the code in which you are setting the value.

Comment: I used a custom setter as listed above

Comment: I mean, where do you expect that setter to run?

Comment: checkbox in fragment -> trigger listener -> change value of mutable list in viewModel, once value in mutableList is set, run validateData

Answer (score 1):

It actually did.

I'm assuming that what you really want it's to trigger `validateData` each time a String is added or removed from your list.

You can write a custom list using `implementation by delegation`[[1]](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/delegation.html#implementation-by-delegation):

```
class MList(
    private val list: MutableList<String> = mutableListOf(),
    private val listener: () -> Unit
) : MutableList<String> by list {

    override fun add(element: String) = 
        list.add(element).also { listener.invoke() }

    override fun remove(element: String) =
        list.remove(element).also { listener.invoke() }

    ...    

}
```

And use it like this:

```
class Foo {

    var stringList = MList { validateData() } // Now each time stringList.add() is called validateData will be triggered

    private fun validateData(){ ... }

}
```