# Kotlin MutableMap getter and setter not working as expected

Tags: kotlin, operator-overloading

In a class I have a `MutableMap` which I want to declare a getter and a setter, like this:

```
open class StringList() {
    private val list= mutableListOf<String>()
    var values: MutableMap<String, String>
        get() {
            println("get member")        // this is printed.. twice
            return mutableMapOf<String, String>()
        }
        set(value) {
            println("set member")        // this is not printed
        }
     fun add(s: String, aObject: Any? = null): Int {
        list.add(s)
        return list.count() - 1
    }
}
```

But when I run the code, like this:

```
var sl = StringList()
sl.add("user=amo")
sl.values["user"] = "other"
val r = sl.values["user"]
```

I realize that the execution is going twice to the getter, and none to the setter.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding but you are never calling the setter, you are calling the getter twice. To call the setter would be s1.values = mutableMapOf etc but you are referencing s1.values twice as a getter, the first time then setting one entry bit not setting the map

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I think I understand what you're trying to do. You want some side effect to happen when a value is added or retrieved from the MutableMap, right?

The getter and setter for the property have nothing to do with that. They are the getter and setter for the property, a reference to a MutableMap. They are not the getter and setter of values *within* the map itself.

There are two different strategies you could use to do this:

1) Create your own map class that has side effects. The easiest way to do this is to by subclassing an existing MutableMap implementation like HashMap.

```
open class StringList() {
    private val list = mutableListOf<String>()
    val values = object: HashMap<String, String>(){
        override fun get(key: String): String? {
            println("Retrieved map value for key $key") // Side effect here
            return super.get(key)
        }

        override fun put(key: String, value: String): String? {
            println("Put key value pair $key / $value") // Side effect here
            return super.put(key, value)
        }
    }

    //...
}
```

2) Write your own accessors that pass the calls along to the map accessors and put your side effects there. This will force you to call these specific functions rather than accessing the map directly from outside the class, so you probably want to make the map property `protected` or `private`.

```
open class StringList() {
    private val list = mutableListOf<String>()
    private val values = mutableMapOf<String, String>()

    //...

    fun putMapValue(key: String, value: String) {
        println("Put key value pair $key / $value") // Side effect here
        values[key] = value
    }

    fun getMapValue(key: String): String? {
        println("Retrieved map value for key $key") // Side effect here
        return values[key]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've answered a similar question with a `List` instead of a `MutableMap` couple days ago see [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61051656/2754562)

Here is the version with `MutableMap`

```
class MMap<T, U>(
        private val map: MutableMap<T, U> = mutableMapOf(),
        private val getter: ((T) -> Unit)? = null,
        private val setter: ((U) -> Unit)? = null
) : MutableMap<T, U> by map {

    override fun put(key: T, value: U): U? = 
        map.put(key, value).also { setter?.invoke(value) }

    override fun get(key: T): U? = 
         map[key].also { getter?.invoke(key) }
}
```

Usage:

```
var values = MMap<String, String>(
    getter = { println("get member $it") },
    setter = { println("set member $it") }
)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Ok, so this is the correct behavior of the getter, but do you know how can I have a syntax like `l.values["user"] = "other"` and go throught the setter??

Comment: Take my other answer as a starting point. I'll do it and update my code soon

Comment: Updated with the map version of my preview answer

Answer (score 1):

It happens because the `setter` of a variable isn't invoked when its `content` changes, but only when there's an assigment, and in your case, you haven't ever assigned it.

```kotlin
var sl = StringList()
// Doesn't invoke the setter.
sl.add("user=amo")
// .values invokes the getter.
sl.values["user"] = "other"
// .values invokes the getter again.
val r = sl.values["user"]
// Invokes the setter since you made an assignment (this line is just an example on how to invoke the setter).
sl.values = mutableMapOf()
```

Comment: So is not possible to have this kind of syntax `sl.values["user"] = "other"` to trigger the setter??

Comment: No, I think you have a fundamental misunderstanding of what the getter and setter do. The setter changes the value of the map `sl`. You can't trigger a setter without passing it a new value. In this case, the new value would be a whole new MutableMap. Your getter is also fundamentally flawed, because it returns a brand new MutableMap every time it's accessed, so once you modify it, and go back to retrieve values from it later, those values will be gone.

Comment: This syntax translates to `sl.getValues().set("user", "other")`. And no, you can't make it call `setValues()`.

Comment: Great explanation @Tenfour04, let me review my code :)

Comment: I saw now your question, Tenfour04 and AlexeyRomanov said it all.